# Help requested with using custom model in caret() package

Tags: neural-networks, caret

The caret package (terrific btw) has a lot of models built in but if you want to use a model that is not built in, there is a way as described in outline here http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/custom_models.html. Reproducing the example given there works just fine.

I'm attempting to do this for the grnn() general regression neural network model and have run into problems I can't fix. My reproducible code example is:

```
library(caret)
x <- rep(1:100); y <- x^2+x*rnorm(100,0,1); tr <- data.frame(y=y,x=x)
grnnFit <- function(dat, params) smooth(learn(dat), sigma=params$sigma) #train
    grnnPred <- function(mod, newx) guess(mod, as.matrix(newx)) #predict
    grnnSort <- function(x) x[order(x$sigma),] #sort results
#list of params/functions
lpgrnn <- list(library="grnn",
  type="Regression",
  parameters=data.frame(parameter="sigma", class="numeric", label="Sigma"),
  grid=data.frame(sigma=c(.1, .2, .3)), #only one tuning parameter sigma
  fit=grnnFit,
  predict=grnnPred,
  prob=NULL,
  sort=grnnSort)

set.seed(998)
fitControl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
set.seed(825)
res <- train(y=tr[,-1], x=tr[,1], method=lpgrnn, metric="RMSE", trControl = fitControl)
```

The error message is:

> res <- train(y=tr[,-1], x=tr[,1], method=lpgrnn, metric="RMSE", trControl = fitControl)
>     Error in train.default(y = tr[, -1], x = tr[, 1], method = lpgrnn, metric = "RMSE",  : 
>     attempt to apply non-function

getModelInfo("grnn") return an empty list

```
> getModelInfo("grnn")
named list()
>
```

as opposed to other models, e.g. getModelInfo("nnet") returns

```
> getModelInfo("nnet")
$nnet
    $nnet$label
[1] "Neural Network"

$nnet$library
[1] "nnet"

$nnet$loop
NULL

$nnet$type
[1] "Classification" "Regression"    

$nnet$parameters
  parameter   class         label
1      size numeric #Hidden Units
2     decay numeric  Weight Decay

$nnet$grid
function (x, y, len = NULL) 
expand.grid(size = ((1:len) * 2) - 1, decay = c(0, 10^seq(-1, 
    -4, length = len - 1)))

$nnet$fit
function (x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) 
{
    dat <- x
    dat$.outcome <- y
        if (!is.null(wts)) {
            out <- nnet(.outcome ~ ., data = dat, weights = wts, 
                size = param$size, decay = param$decay, ...)
        }
        else out <- nnet(.outcome ~ ., data = dat, size = param$size, 
        decay = param$decay, ...)
    out
}

$nnet$predict
function (modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) 
{
    if (modelFit$problemType == "Classification") {
        out <- predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "class")
    }
    else {
        out <- predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "raw")
    }
    out
}

$nnet$prob
function (modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) 
{
    out <- predict(modelFit, newdata)
    if (ncol(as.data.frame(out)) == 1) {
        out <- cbind(out, 1 - out)
        dimnames(out)[[2]] <- rev(modelFit$obsLevels)
    }
    out
}

$nnet$varImp
function (object, ...) 
{
    imp <- caret:::GarsonWeights(object, ...)
    if (ncol(imp) > 1) {
        imp <- cbind(apply(imp, 1, mean), imp)
        colnames(imp)[1] <- "Overall"
    }
    else {
        imp <- as.data.frame(imp)
        names(imp) <- "Overall"
    }
    if (!is.null(object$xNames)) 
            rownames(imp) <- object$xNames
    imp
}

$nnet$predictors
function (x, ...) 
if (hasTerms(x)) predictors(x$terms) else NA

$nnet$tags
[1] "Neural Network"    "L2 Regularization"

$nnet$levels
function (x) 
x$lev

$nnet$sort
function (x) 
x[order(x$size, -x$decay), ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getModelInfo` shows you the code for built-in models. `grnn` is not wrapped by this package, so you won't find code there.

There are a lot of avoidable problems. First, you have your data mixed up:

```
x <- rep(1:100); y <- x^2+x*rnorm(100,0,1); tr <- data.frame(y=y,x=x)
```

`tr[,-1]` is `x` so `y=tr[,-1]` is wrong.

For your code, there are a few things:

- the `grid` module should be a function instead of a data frame. That is where the `attempt to apply non-function` comes from. However:
- the arguments to the `pred` and `fit` modules do not include most of the required arguments listed on the help page.

For this particular package:

- You might have to do something like this:

  ```
  grnnFit <- function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, weights, classProbs, ...) {
                      dat <- x
                      dat$.outcome <- y
                          smooth(learn(dat, variable.column = ncol(dat)), 
                                 sigma = param$sigma)}
  ```
- Also, for this package, you might have to use `guess` inside of `apply`.

My impression is that you should slow down and read the documentation (it really looks like you did not). There are some weird things about `grnn` (to me) and it has almost no documentation. That should be the hard part, so read the caret web page and get the easy parts down.

Max

** Update**
As Max alluded to, grnn() guess() method can only compute a prediction for a single vector so this had to be wrapped in a for loop.

The new working code:

```
#Using caret() to determine the optimum value for grnn() smooth parameter    
grnnFit <- function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, weights, classProbs, ...) {
  #use argument names EXACTLY as here in all functions
  library(grnn)
  dat <- data.frame(y, x)
  s <- smooth(learn(dat), sigma=param$sigma)
  return(s)
}

grnnPred <- function(modelFit, newdata, preProc=NULL, submodels=NULL) {
  library(grnn)
  library(foreach)
  xlst <- split(newdata, 1:nrow(newdata))
  pred <- foreach(i = xlst, .combine = rbind) %do% {
    #grnn() can only compute a prediction for one sample at a time
    guess(modelFit, as.matrix(i)) #provide x values as matrix
  }
}

grnnSort <- function(x) {
  x[order(x$sigma),]
  print(x)
}

grnnGrid <- function(x, y, len=NULL) {
  #only one tuning parameter sigma
  data.frame(sigma=seq(1,4,.05)) #search range
}

grnnLev <- function(x) {
  lev(x)
}

#list of params/functions
lpgrnn <- list(
  library="grnn",
  type="Regression",
  parameters=data.frame(parameter="sigma", class="numeric", label="Sigma"),
  grid=grnnGrid,
  fit=grnnFit,
  predict=grnnPred,
  prob=NULL,
  levels=grnnLev,
  sort=grnnSort)

library(caret)
set.seed(123)
x1 <- rep(1:100) + rnorm(100,0,1)
x2 <- rep(1:100) + rnorm(100,0,1)
tr <- data.frame(y=x1*x2, x1, x2)
set.seed(998)
fitControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", repeats=5)
set.seed(825)
res <- train(y~., data=tr, method=lpgrnn, metric="RMSE", trControl = fitControl)
print(res)
print(res$finalModel$sigma)
plot(res)
```

[image: sigma versus RMSE]

Comment: Excellent advice Max. Many thanks. Mea culpa for not properly realizing what is required and what is particular to the example.